# ECMAScript/Node: is it possible to save an object instance or context to the filesystem?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to save an object (instance of a class) to the filesystem including its internal values?

*Please do not flag as off-topic.* I understand that even if this is somehow achievable, it is not common practice. It doesn't matter either if it is hacky. I am just curious if it can be achieved because it is sunday 8 oclock and I had a long day.

```
function Node() {
    let x = Math.random()
    this.data = function() {
        return x
    }
}

let node1 = new Node()
// save it to the disk somehow as node1
saveNode('node1', node1)
// load it back from the disk into memory somehow, perhaps using eval??
let savedNode = loadNode('node1')

console.log(
   savedNode.data(), 
   node1.data()
) /* these should be the same */
```

You can stringify an object including its functions by using a 'modifier' function as second argument in JSON.stringify but that won't do the trick here.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for serialization?

Comment: Storing functions would be really inefficient. May just store all props, then rebind the functions on load? ( that wont work for closures)

Comment: _"You can stringify an object including its functions by using a 'modifier' function as second argument in JSON.stringify"_ Was not aware of ability to stringify a function using `JSON.stringify()`, which should assist in providing the solution to inquiry. Do you mean use `replacer` function to catch iteration and call `.toString()` on function reference? Can you demonstrate at stacksnippets or jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It is not possible to write the state of variables you have no access to. Imagine not only an `x`, but also a random `y`, and that `data()` returns their product. There is no way for code outside that function to know the actual values of `x` or `y`.

Answer (score 2):

Only if the object (or class) cooperates. No, it's not possible in general to access the values hidden behind a closure scope.

You can however do something like

```
class Node {
    constructor(x = Math.random()) {
        this.data = () => x;
    }
    toJSON() {
        return {x: this.data()};
    }
    static fromJSON(obj) {
        return new this(obj.x);
    }
}

const fs = require("fs");
function save(name, obj) {
    fs.writeFileSync(`./${name}.json`, JSON.stringify(obj), "utf-8");
}
function load(constr, name) {
    return constr.fromJSON(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./${name}.json`, "utf-8");
}

let node1 = new Node();
save('node1', node1);
let savedNode = load(Node, 'node1');
console.log(savedNode.data(), node1.data())
```